# How can the output elements put in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function main() {
    var increase = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    for(var i=0;i<prices.length;i++)
    {
    var b=prices[i]+increase;
    console.log(+b);
   }
}
```

Here the output is displayed in seperate elements but I want all the elements in a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just create array and push into it:

```js
function main() {
    let result = [];
    var increase = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    for(var i=0;i<prices.length;i++)
    {
    var b=prices[i]+increase;
    result.push(b);
   }
  
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You can change return to console.log

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your result in an array and then log the output. Check the below code

```
var output = []
function main() {
    var increase = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    var prices = [98.99, 15.2, 20, 1026];
    //your code goes here
    for(var i=0;i<prices.length;i++)
    {
    var b=prices[i]+increase;
    output.push(+b);
   }
}
main()
console.log(output)
```